# Controlling Prolog variable value selection

Tags: prolog, evaluation, prolog-defaulty

Inspired by [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595786/using-operator-to-save-variables-in-a-list) I tried to implement something that would enumerate the possibilities for a boolean expression. However, I'm having trouble with variable choice. Here's my intended outcome:

```
?- eval(X^Y, R).
R = 0^0;
R = 0^1;
R = 1^0;
R = 1^1;
no.
```

Here's my code:

```
:- op(200, yfx, ^).

split(V, R) :- var(V), R = 0.
split(V, R) :- var(V), R = 1.
split(X ^ Y, XP ^ YP) :- split(X, XP), split(Y, YP).
```

This already doesn't do what I want even for this simple case:

```
?- split(Y, R).
R = 0 ;
R = 1 ;
Y = _G269^_G270,
R = 0^0 ;
Y = _G269^_G270,
R = 0^1 ;
Y = _G269^ (_G275^_G276),
R = 0^ (0^0) ;
Y = _G269^ (_G275^_G276),
R = 0^ (0^1) ;
Y = _G269^ (_G275^ (_G281^_G282)),
R = 0^ (0^ (0^0)) .
```

So, I can see what the problem is here, which is that on the way through `split(Y, YP)` Prolog has exhausted the first two clauses, so it winds up in `split(X^Y, ...)` again, unifying my `Y` with `X'^Y'`, essentially. I am just not sure what I need to do to close off that path except at the outset where I have the structure `^/2`.

I'd also like this to work with nested structures, so I can't just eliminate the recursive processing of the branches.

**Edit**: without operators

If the `op/3` is bothering you, consider this formulation:

```
eval(and(X,Y), R).
R = and(0,0);
R = and(0,1);
R = and(1,0);
R = and(1,1);
no.
```

This would be the code in that case:

```
split(V, R) :- var(V), R = 0.
split(V, R) :- var(V), R = 1.
split(and(X,Y), and(XP,YP)) :- split(X, XP), split(Y, YP).
```

Bear in mind I'd still like it to work with recursive formulations like `and(and(X,Y),and(Y,Z))` etc.

Comment: The link to the earlier question is broken.

Comment: @GuyCoder When you get another 1000 rep, it won't be. :)

Comment: @GuyCoder you won't need to see it to answer my question

Comment: I am still trying to understand the question. Normally I do these problems as a term rewrite with the symbols being abstract. As soon as I saw `op(200, yfx, ^).` it is throwing me off.

Comment: @GuyCoder so replace it with `foo(X,Y)`; the operator has nothing to do with the problem, it's just harder to understand why you'd want this without something that looks like an AST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Main problem: Defaulty representation

The core problem in this case is the **defaulty representation** you are using to represent Boolean expressions.

By "defaulty" I mean that you cannot clearly distinguish the cases by **pattern matching**: In your case, a variable `V` may denote *either*

- one of the propositional constants `0` and `1`, *or*
- a compound expression of the form `A^B`.

Due to this shortcoming, you cannot cleanly express a constraint of the form "the variable `X` stands only for one of the two propositional constants" within your program.

---

## A way out: Clean representation

A declarative way out is to use a **clean representation** *instead*.

For example, suppose we arbitrarily use `v/1` to distinguish variables that only denote the propositional constants, then we have:

- `v(X)` to denote the propositional variable `X`
- `A^B` to denote a *compound expression*.

Clearly, since the principal functors and arities are different (`v/1` vs. `(^)/2`), we can distinguish the cases by pattern matching alone.

With this *new* representation, your snippet becomes:

```
split(v(V), V) :- V = 0.
split(v(V), V) :- V = 1.
split(X^Y, XP ^ YP) :-
        split(X, XP),
        split(Y, YP).
```

Example query:

```
?- split(v(X)^v(Y), R).
X = Y, Y = 0,
R = 0^0 ;
X = 0,
Y = 1,
R = 0^1 ;
X = 1,
Y = 0,
R = 1^0 ;
X = Y, Y = 1,
R = 1^1.
```

Note that this *still* works in *all directions*, also in the **most general case**:

```
?- split(Expr, R).
Expr = v(0),
R = 0 ;
Expr = v(1),
R = 1 ;
Expr = v(0)^v(0),
R = 0^0 ;
Expr = v(0)^v(1),
R = 0^1 ;
etc.
```

As a rule of thumb, once you have to use an extra-logical predicate like `var/1` in your code, there is little hope to retain its logical purity and monotonicity. Aim for clean representations to preserve these properties.

Sometimes, it is unavoidable to use defaulty representations, for example, because you want to make the input easier for users. In such cases, aim to quickly convert them to clean ones before starting the actual reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for writing all this, you have (as usual) cleared up something very fundamental for me!

Comment: You're welcome. This is really a very fundamental aspect: Many problems and shortcomings (also in many Prolog books!) stem from using a defaulty representation. It is so called because to handle it, you need a "default" case. This typically yields wrong results in general, because it essentially requires you to *commit* to only one possible outcome if you encounter a variable, even though declaratively, it can stand for other entities too. Clean representations make it perfectly clear what a variable stands for, and so allow more general programs. Note that the Prolog AST is defaulty too!

Comment: ... and `library(clpfd/clpz)` has just the same problem, solved by adding a functor `(#)/1` such that you can write (with resp. op): `#X + #Y #= #Z`

Answer (score 3):

At some point of time I wrote a very small program that seems to be more or less what you are looking for. I really hope I am not totally misreading your question. You can check [this SWISH program](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/boolean.pl) for the whole program. There are a few differences, like using `f` and `t` instead of 0 and 1, or using `and` and `or` instead of `^` and `v`. However, the basic idea is the same as yours (I think).

If I remove some of the unnecessary stuff for demonstrating, then this would be the program:

```
:- op(100, fy, ?).
:- op(500, yfx, and).
:- op(500, yfx, or).

table(F, T) :-
        term_variables(F, Vs),
        bagof(R-Vs, bl(F, R), T).

bl(?X, R) :-
        v(X, R).
bl(X and Y, R) :-
        bl(X, R0),
        and_bl(R0, Y, R).
bl(X or Y, R) :-
        bl(X, R0),
        or_bl(R0, Y, R).

v(f, f).
v(t, t).

and_bl(f, _, f).
and_bl(t, Y, R) :- bl(Y, R).

or_bl(f, Y, R) :- bl(Y, R).
or_bl(t, _, t).
```

The main point here is that I have a pure relation, my `v/2`, which simply states that the value of `true` is `true` and the value of `false` is `false`. Then, I am using a mutually recursive definition for actually evaluating the boolean expressions, which eventually bottoms out at `v/2`.

I decided to "tag" the boolean variables myself, so instead of `X` you would have to write `?X`. If I remember correctly, at the time I realized I need a way to explicitly say if I have a Boolean variable within an expression, or if the whole expression is still "unknown". In other words, this: `?X` is either `t` or `f` and this: `Expr` can be `?X`, or `not ?X`, or `?X and ?Y`, or `?X or ?Y`, or `not (?X and ?Y)`, and so on.

Tagging the variable with `?X` is what avoids the "defaulty representation" is [what @mat explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41622609/1812457). Importantly, without explicitly tagging, I don't see a way for telling apart Boolean variables from Boolean expressions.

Here is how you can use it:

```
?- bl(?t and ?X, R).
X = R, R = f ;
X = R, R = t.

?- bl(?t or ?X, R).
R = t.

?- bl(?A or (?B and ?C), R).
A = B, B = R, R = f ;
A = C, C = R, R = f,
B = t ;
A = f,
B = C, C = R, R = t ;
A = R, R = t.

?- table(?A or (?B and ?A), R).
R = [f-[f, f], f-[f, t], t-[t, _7734]].
```

Comment: If you don't manually tag the boolean variables yourself, is there actually a way forward with `compound/1`? The `?/1` structure you're using here is making it so that you never catch an unadorned variable in `bl/2` and I feel this may be a critical aspect of your solution.

Comment: @DanielLyons What do you mean by "unadorned variable"? If you just put a free variable as the expression, the solver should ideally generate possible expressions; I got lazy at that point and didn't program this properly. The problem of course is in what order to enumerate the (infinitely many) possible expressions.

Comment: @mat has cleared this up for me with his answer, but I really appreciate your answer. The `?/1` is a very clever idea that reads well! Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Yes, `(?)/1` is the key to a clean representation in this example, +1! Using `(?)/1` is a good idea to solve this in many cases. Sometimes, a different dedicated operator is a better fit. For example, in the context of CLP(FD),  `(#)/1` is a good choice to distinguish variables that stand for concrete integers from compound expressions.

Comment: @mat I have forgotten my reasons for taking `?` as the "Boolean variable" unary operator. Maybe it is just easy to type and didn't clash with anything I could think of at the moment.

Comment: @DanielLyons Now after I slept over it is slowly coming back. I _think_ you must tag the Boolean variables explicitly if you want to be able to have either a Boolean within an expression or a whole expression as the first argument to `bl/2`. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Boris: Many decades ago, in Concurrent Prolog and the like, there were variables written `X?` thus with a postfix `?`. A notation which seems quite attractive. Actually, `library(clpfd)` did contain this op first/ However, it does not fit with xpce's infix `?`. And `#X #> 3` looks quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

There are already two good answers, a pure one and the shorter one using `term_variables/2`. I would still like to address a detail:

> So, I can see what the problem is here, which is that on the way through `split(Y, YP)` Prolog has exhausted the first two clauses, so it winds up in `split(X^Y, ...)` again, unifying my `Y` with `X'^Y'`, essentially. I am just not sure what I need to do to close off that path except at the outset where I have the structure `^/2`.

If you don't want to perform the head unification with `X^Y` if the first argument is a variable, pull the unification out of the head. Nothing forces you to put the term `X^Y` there! What you want to do is to only consider your last clause if the previous two clauses did not apply. The previous two clauses were guarded by `var/1`, so you can guard the last one with `nonvar/1`:

```
split(V, R) :- var(V), R = 0.
split(V, R) :- var(V), R = 1.
split(Term, SplitTerm) :-
    nonvar(Term),
    Term = X ^ Y,
    split(X, XP),
    split(Y, YP),
    SplitTerm = XP ^ YP.
```

With this your examples work as intended:

```
?- split(Y, R).
R = 0 ;
R = 1 ;
false.

?- split(X^Y, R).
R = 0^0 ;
R = 0^1 ;
R = 1^0 ;
R = 1^1 ;
false.
```

**Edit:** As mat pointed out in the comments, using tests like `var/1` can get you into all kinds of trouble.

One problem is that there are various levels of instantiation that you would have to check carefully: mat's example query of `split(1, R)` fails with the above code (it should succeed with `R = 1`). This is because `1` falls into the `nonvar` case but does not unify with `_^_`. If we're going this way, we must distinguish not just the `var` and `nonvar` cases, but rather `var`, `ground`, and `nonvar`-but-not-`ground`. This gets a bit messy.

Another issue is the query `split(V, R), V = 1`, which is declaratively equivalent to the query above, but succeeds twice, including with the solution `R = V`. This is because this definition of `split/2` (deliberately) avoided introducing sharing between its arguments. Whether we do want that sharing or not depends on the specification.

I won't try to give a fully robust solution with instantiation tests as my point was not that this is the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on this! I really like this solution to the question-as-asked, even though @mat has illuminated the underlying problem behind the question.

Comment: That's incorrect. Check it out, using for example the query: `?- split(V, R), V = 1.` This yields both `R = 0` **and** `R = 1`. In addition, it's also not **monotonic**: If I write it declaratively equivalently as `?- split(1, R).`, it **fails** instead. As a rule of thumb, once you need to resort to `var/1` and other extra-logical predicates, you will introduce mistakes and can no longer use your predicates in all directions (which is what we expect from true relations). Consider an edit to clarify these shortcomings! I think it would be instructive to see such issues explained in your post!

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I upvoted this for the added explanation, which is very helpful.