# Prolog - Take operation elements

Tags: prolog

I need a predicate `elements(X,L)` where X is an operation like `neg X`, `X and Y` and returns a list L with all the elements from the operation, like `[X,Y]`.

I already have these:

```
elements(neg X, [X]).
elements(X and Y, [X,Y]).
elements(X or Y, [X,Y]).
elements(X imp Y, [X,Y]).
```

But I don´t know how to make it work with complex operations like `X imp (Y or Z)`.

Comment: If this is homework please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1243762)

Comment: You should also provide example code you have written and explain where your problem is with your code.

Comment: @Guy Coder Yes, this is homework, but I'm still a begginer and I had no idea what more could I do. Anyway, thank you for your tips, and I'll see if I can make it work.

Comment: @Guy Coder My teacher says it's ok, as long as I provide my sources.

Comment: @Guy Coder Yes, I'm reading the information in the websites you sent me. I really do appreciate your help, and I'm only going to learn by doing things myself. I just posted this, because I needed some guidance.

Comment: um, `term_variables/2`?

Comment: Of interest: [Predicate term_variables/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_variables/2)

Comment: @GuyCoder I'll take a crack at it but I really don't know what the OP wants.

Comment: @DanielLyons I would prefer something simple, since I'm only a begginer.

Comment: Don't worry, @MiguelAndrade, I only do simple. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not great at picking operator precedences but here's what I have for your input:

```
:- op(100, fx, neg).
:- op(200, xfy, and).
:- op(200, xfy, or).
:- op(300, xfy, imp).

elements(Term, Variables) :- term_variables(Term, Variables).
```

This seems to do what you specified:

```
?- elements(X imp (Y and Z), Q).
Q = [X, Y, Z].
```

Is there more to your problem than this?

Comment: I have the opposite problem, I am not good at Prolog op. Your precedence looks right, see: [Order of precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence)

Comment: Thank you and @GuyCoder for your help. That's exactly what I needed. I actually did some research, but I didn't found that predicate.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade Don't worry about not finding it, I should have looked for it first myself. I was hung up writing a parser when the easier answer was right there. You can also give an upvote in addition to the accept vote.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade if it weren't for the question I asked today I wouldn't have known about `term_variable/2` either. :)

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks for checking, I usually get precedence all monkeyed up, but I use `op/3` _a lot_ :)

Comment: @DanielLyons It doesn't hurt to [link your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41621414/1812457). It increases visibility and might help someone else along the way (your question should now be prominently displayed in the right-hand pane)